# Inheritance Tax on money received abroad

Tags: united-kingdom, capital-gains-tax, inheritance

I am a dual UK and Bangladeshi citizen who recently inherited money from my father in Bangladesh. I want to bring the money over to purchase a flat in the UK. Would i be liable to inheritance tax?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your father had no UK assets, and didn't live in the UK in the last 20 years, my understanding is that there shouldn't be any UK tax to pay according to [this gov.uk page](https://www.gov.uk/inheritance-tax/when-someone-living-outside-the-uk-dies).  I've no idea about what happens in Bangladesh though.